# Expression of closed intervals appeared in the $m$-th stage of construction of the Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, cantor-set

I am reading [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1963-106-02/S0002-9947-1963-0143186-0/S0002-9947-1963-0143186-0.pdf) and have a question related to the following line:

> **Quote:** Let $D'$ be the collection of all closed discs in the $xy$ plane whose
> diameters are the intervals in the $x$-axis
> $$\left[\frac{n+1/3}{3^m},\frac{n+4/3}{3^m}\right],$$ where $0\leq n\leq
>  3^m$ is an integer which admits a triadic expansion free from
> $1$'s;...

Now, to construct the Cantor set, we first divide $[0,1]$ into three closed intervals of equal length and discard the interior of the middle one, so we have two closed intervals $C_0, C_2$. Then in $C_0, C_2$ we do the same procedure: divide each of them into three closed intervals of equal length, and discard the interior of the middle one; so we have four closed intervals $C_{0,0}, C_{0,2}, C_{2,0}, C_{2,2}$. And so on.

> **Question:** In the quoted line, are the diameters nothing but all closed intervals that appeared in the $m$-th stage of construction of
> the Cantor set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since the interval $[1, 3^{-m}]$ appears in the $m-$th stage of the construction of the Cantor set, however, $\frac{n + 1/3}{3^m} \ne 1$ for any $n, m$ since otherwise we have
$$
3n + 1 = 3^{m+1}
$$
which is impossible since $3$ does not divide $1$.

Comment: Can you explain the part **integer which admits a triadic expansion free from 1's*, I mean what are first few diameters then?

Comment: Start with $m=1$, write each non-negative integer $n$ not exceeding $3^m$ in base 3,  and if this representation contains no 1's, you can compute the endpoints of the interval as in your post. Set $m=2$, repeat and so on.